# how can i do to dim background screen when open new message box or other dialog box

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I am creating a project that include login and sign up . In that, I want to do background screen in dim state when open some dialog box or others (like login or sign up box) .

Comment: Do you have some logical reason for failing to add the [tag:java] tag (with its 54.8K followers)?

Comment: *"I wanna do.."*  I want to read post from people who can spell 'want to' - or that use a spell checker.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Glass Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) to paint over the entire JFrame.

Just set the background of the Glass Pane to a color with transparency when you make the glass pane visible.